# Rails 3 / Bundler gem: 'undefined method `setup' for Bundler:Module (NoMethodError)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

It can be traced back to config/boot.rb, line 7:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
```

This is with Bundler 0.8.1 supposedly installed:

```
../Users/ashley$ sudo gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-0.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-0.8.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-0.8.1...
```

Everything I've done has followed [this guide](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/1/1/getting-a-new-app-running-on-edge). Anyone have any clue what's wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try gem install bundler --prerelease

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. However now 'gem bundle' doesn't work?

http://pastie.org/807869

Comment: @ashleyw gem bundle is history, use bundle

Comment: @ursm Could you please help on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919397/setup-undefined-method-plain-specs-for-bundlerrubygemsintegration0x000

Answer (score 2):

ursm is right. Make sure you have old bundlers removed as well.

Comment: Could you also please help on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919397/setup-undefined-method-plain-specs-for-bundlerrubygemsintegration0x000